# Add two criterias in VBA range filter

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to select a range of values based on filter 1 and filter 2 and then delete all those values; so that I am only left with filter1 and filter2 values in column. I am able to add one filter, but I am not able to add two filters. Please help/guide.

Code:

```
Case "Sheet-1"
                         iCol = 2
                         Rows("4:4").Select      
                         Selection.AutoFilter
                         ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$WXR$99999").AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:= _
                         "<>*ABC*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<>XYZ*"
                         Rows("5:5").Select 
                         Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                         Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                         Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                         ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$WXR$99999").AutoFilter Field:=iCol
```

Comment: Have you tried just recording a macro and using the code from manually clicking on the filters?

Comment: @Constuntine : sorry I didnt understand you

Comment: If you go to the Developer tab and click `Record Macro`. It will give you the VBA code for everything you are doing. So just click `Record Macro`. Then select what you want to filter. Go to the `Data` tab and select filter. It will place an arrow on whatever data you selected. Click the arrow and place the filters. After that, go back and click `Stop Recording`. Then go to your code editor and there will be a module in there that has the code you need to filter. Then simply copy and paste it where you need it.

Comment: I don't understand your filter. Any value will be either <> "*ABC*" or <>"XYZ". Perhaps you mean to use xlAnd

Comment: @Constuntine : thank you so much.. i did what you told

Comment: Posted in the answers so you can mark as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the Developer tab and click `Record Macro`. It will give you the VBA code for everything you are doing. So just click `Record Macro`. Then select what you want to filter. Go to the `Data` tab and select filter. It will place an arrow on whatever data you selected. Click the arrow and place the filters. After that, go back and click `Stop Recording`. Then go to your code editor and there will be a module in there that has the code you need to filter. Then simply copy and paste it where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

What is your criteria in your second filter? I think that one was missing.

Comment: thanks san-san. this question is resolved.. i did what Constuntine  told in above comment